# Javascript function not working when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not that familiar with JavaScript, but have the code below in a *.htm* file. The function doesn't appear to be called when it should; It should be called when opening the page directly i.e

```
www.site.com/12345.htm
```

changes the URL to

```
site.com/#12345.htm
```

and load the relevant scripts and css.

It shouldn't be called unless opening directly. i.e going to www.site.com/ shouldn't call that as *index.htm* already has the css/script loaded instantly

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> Introduction </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isTOCLoaded() {
        //this function for loading the topic within the application if loaded by itself
        //i.e. open the topic .htm file or as search engines link
        var url = window.location.href;
        var baseUrl = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        var topicFile = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
        var newUrl = baseUrl + "#" + topicFile;
        location.href = newUrl;
        return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="t57117" class="heading1">Introduction</h1>

<input id="topicId" type="hidden" value="57117" />
<input id="topicDescription" type="hidden" value="Introduction" />
<input id="footer-modified" type="hidden" value="Last modified: 17/12/2015 8:18:59 a.m." />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to call it. nothing called itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to invoke your function if you want it to be evaluated:

```
<title> Introduction </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isTOCLoaded() {
        //this function for loading the topic within the application if loaded by itself
        //i.e. open the topic .htm file or as search engines link
        var url = window.location.href;
        var baseUrl = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        var topicFile = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
        var newUrl = baseUrl + "#" + topicFile;
        location.href = newUrl;
        return false;
    }

    // ADDED: run the function
    isTOCLoaded();
</script>
</head>
```

In JavaScript, the `function` keyword is used to **declare** a function for later use, it does not actually run the contents of your function until the first time it is called.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. This fixed the issue.